# A 10cm long trace runs through the middle of a 2 layer PCB and cuts the ground plane in half one one layer. How to prevent this?

Tags: layout, ground-loop

Basically, my PCB has one side that will be facing an enclosure's panel with IO. This side has a slide switch that needs to power a 12V power relay that draws 37.5mA when turned ON, but is **located in the opposite side of the PCB**. If you worry that the sliding switch will power the relay, do not, I have used a power P-channel MOSFET close to the relay so the switch trace will draw virtually no current and a pull-up is placed to put the MOSFET in saturation. **And the trace that pulls down the MOSFET is connected to ground near the switch.**

Since this sliding switch is in the exact middle of one edge of the PCB and my board is crammed with components, but I happened to have a direct connection through the middle of the PCB, I decided to do exactly this. **The problem is that the trace cuts in half the top ground plane, but not the bottom.**

What should I do in this case? Should I route the trace back and forth between the two layers to reduce possible ground loops, or should I via stitch around the trace? Are there any better methods to this like maybe using a jumper wire that runs over the board?

[image: Schematic and basic diagram]

[image: Layout with highlighted trace]
[image: Top layer unfinished]
[image: Bottom layer unfinished]

Comment: A 4 layer pcb doesnt cost much extra these days. Also, you could use solderable jumper links, or switch plans with vias. If you post photos of your artwork, we can decide better!

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent I need a 2 oz. copper PCB, and 4 layer ones are way to expensive for my design, plus, all the SMD components fit in one side of the board, while the opposite side is mainly used for high power traces here and there.

Comment: Soldered jumper is my recommendation.

Comment: just to confirm: in your layout, all the bottom layer traces that are currently there are simply ground, right? Because if they aren't, your problem is not that the top layer has an interrupted ground plane, but that the bottom layer doesn't look like it does.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the ground plane is not shown in the second image, since it makes things more confusing. Both layers have a ground plane with ocasional traces. I have not  placed vias to connect ground to the apropriate components yet, and I plan to use many vias to properly stitch both planes together.

Comment: yes, but you're worrying about breaking the top ground plane, which you don't really need, while you are interrupting the current return paths where it actually matters already on the ground plane. You're solving the wrong problem!

Comment: You really need a 4 layer PCB for this.

Comment: The top ground plane really is not a plane. It is already full of holes made by the components. I would not worry about it. Keep the bottom plane pristine. Any ground current paths that need to cross can be routed through the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do th following (Red is signal layer, blue is GND layer).

You can use a .2mm or so trace as its only a small power signal.

**To add an extra:** If you need 2oz copper i would still go four layer 1oz. The traces requiring more current can be routed as polygons on two or more layers with good via stitching. This also improves your GND-Plane impedance as it can be spread across multiple layers.

[image]

Comment: Missing information, my bad! There are some other mosfets that need to enable some digital pins under the big chip in the middle, so the trace must go like I drawn. This is also the main reason I used a flyback diode for the back-EMF of  the relay, and a PMOS to switch on the Relay.

Comment: @StickySli I understand. Honest answer: Go 4layer 1oz, copy the high power polygons on two layers and fill the rest of the inner two layers with GND. Route only on the two outer layers